# Using PreferenceFragment in SherlockFragmentActivity with tabs

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-preferences

I am trying to make a tabbed activity using [ABS](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) SherlockFragmentActivity with a ViewPager, and would like to have one of the tabs to contain a preference activity/fragment.

As ABS does not have a SherlockPreferenceFragment, or any kind of support for PreferenceFragment, I [found](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/43) a possible solution using [UnifiedPreference](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference)

UnifiedPreference works on it's own, demo works great, but if I try to implement it in my ActionBarSherlock powered tabs, it crashes with the message:

```
04-18 03:59:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 03:59:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8437): java.lang.ClassCastException: si.neanonimen.Settings$NetSettingsPrefsFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-18 03:59:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
```

It looks like `UnifiedPreferenceFragment` does not extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.
Is there any way around this? Has anyone managed to get a working example?

My current code is:

Settings:

```
public class Settings extends UnifiedSherlockPreferenceActivity {

    public static String tag = "Settings";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHeaderRes(R.xml.pref_headers);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    public static class NetSettingsPrefsFragment extends UnifiedPreferenceFragment {}
}
```

Tabbed activity:

```
public class FragmentTabs extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private TabHost     mTabHost;
    private ViewPager   mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

        // obviously THIS is the problem
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Nastavitve"), Settings.NetSettingsPrefsFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context               mContext;
        private final TabHost               mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager             mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo>    mTabs   = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            //private final String  tag;
            private final Class<?>  clss;
            private final Bundle    args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                //tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context   mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem like you. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Nothing yet, still waiting for help.

Answer (score 1):

I also need to implement a PreferenceFragment in Android versions prior to Honeycomb (API level 11). As you already have, I found UnifiedPreference library but looking at the source code I see that the UnifiedPreferenceFragment extends the PreferenceFragment from the official Android API, thus not working for < API level 11.

This is another class I've found out there, but I haven't tested it yet:

- [PreferenceListFragment](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=19719977&postcount=1)

Hope it helps!

Have you found another solution? Hopefully the Android folk will add this class to the support library soon!

Cheers,

Comment: I've tried the PrefereceListFragment class and works great! In the link there is also an example implementation to guide you a bit more.

BTW, I extended SherlockListFragment instead of ListFragment and also worked. So there is seamless ABS support for this class.